# SharePoint JSLink override not working

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, jslink

I need to overwrite a multiline sharepoint field by a tooltip but it's not wotking.

```
    (function () {

    var SubjectFiledContext = {};
    SubjectFiledContext.Templates = {};

    SubjectFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
        // Apply the new rendering for Body field on list view

        "subject": { "View": SubjectFiledTemplate}



    };


    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(SubjectFiledContext);

})();

function SubjectFiledTemplate(ctx) {

       var subjectValue =ctx.CurrentItem.subject;

        //This regex expression use to delete html tags from the Body field
        var regex = "/(<([^>]+)>)/ig";



        subjectValue = subjectValue.replace(regex, "");
subjectValue = subjectValue.replace(/<br>/g, "&#013;");



        var newSubjectValue = subjectValue;


        if (subjectValue && subjectValue.length >= 20)
        {
            newSubjectValue = subjectValue.substring(0, 20) + " ...";
        }


        return "<span title='" + subjectValue + "'>" + newSubjectValue+ "</span>";
    }
```

I tried to test it simply :

```
    (function () {

    var SubjectFiledContext = {};
    SubjectFiledContext.Templates = {};

    SubjectFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
        // Apply the new rendering for Body field on list view

        "subject": { "View": "test"}



    };


    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(SubjectFiledContext);

})();
```

Its not working again! I activated/deactivate the MDS feature  and always the same thing, not working!

To call the jslink script on the webpart, I've linked to: `~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/subject_template.js`

Comment: Use the Chrome browser and the Cisar Chrome Extension to create/edit CSR files

Comment: I installed the Cisar Chrome Extension and I published the jslink script but it's not working !

Comment: If you add a JSLink referencing a file with only ``console.log('I executed');`` it should work, then take it from there. ``"View":"test"`` will never work as it expects a Function to return an HTML string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all !

it's fixed it using the  Cisar Chrome Extension and the problem was related to Field internal Name

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the first word in the path from `"~sitecollection"` to `"~site"`

`~site/_catalogs/masterpage/subject_template.js`